# How to display all mapped short cut keys in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts

I seemed to have lost my F12 shortcut key in various apps, I'm guessing that it's mapped to something in Windows.

Is there a way to list all the mapped shortcut keys in windows?

-thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ActiveHotkeys](http://www.tranglos.com/activehotkeys/) will tell you if the shortcut has been claimed or not, but it won't tell you what application has it.  You can close applications until F12 frees up to find out exactly what app is using the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

The updated link to ActiveHotKeys is http://www.tranglos.com/activehotkeys/

(Note that it won't work correctly on 64-bit versions of Windows) :(

Comment: Thanks for telling us! However, this should probably be a comment on the answer already here. And you can edit the answer to fix the url yourself. :)

Comment: Ah yes! Good tip, thanks - done. (I don't have access to comments on other people's posts yet though)

Comment: The [Ethervane ActiveHotkeys portable version](http://www.tranglos.com/dl/activehotkeysportable.zip) runs on my 64-bit Intel i5 Windows7 machine.